# What are the different apk outputs from intelliJ?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

What is the difference between the different .apk outputs when building a signed apk from IntelliJ IDEA?

When I do a signed apk build from IntelliJ Idea (13.1.2) I get three different apk files.

- ../myApp.apk (921 KB)
- ../out/production/myApp/myApp.apk (914 KB)
- ../out/production/myApp/myApp.unaligned.apk (1412 KB)

My guess is unaligned is non compressed and shouldn't be used in the play store. Which one should be used in the playstore?

Note: I am using proguard but not using Ant or Maven.

Answer (score 0):

Use the one you find at `.../out/production/Your App name/yourapp.apk`

Yet again, in properties of the project you can set the custom location for your APK. But I suggest you get used to the default ones since it will be a pain to set up your path each time.